# how do I reference the values from textboxes on form submit that reside in my usercontrol? ASP.NET(VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can't believe I couldn't find an answer to this question after literally hours of searching the web. Is this so basic that everyone just knows how to do this? As you might have guessed I'm new to asp.net(vb).

My situation:
I have a large form that reuses several elements, so I decided to create a usercontrol with some common fields. The problem is when the form is filled out by a user and submitted, how do I reference those values so I can input them to my database???

Example:

```
Using Conn As New SqlConnection(connect)
        Using Cmd As New SqlCommand(SQL, Conn)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acct_Company", txtPartner.Text)
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acct_AccountNum", txtPartnerAccount.Text)
```

So, above two Cmd lines are for normally inserted textboxes in my form, but what would the line look like to reference any usercontrol form fields?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the controls some how to the page that contains the user control. One way to to this is like this (within the control code):

```
Property CompanyName As String
  Get
    Return txtPartner.Text
  End Get
  Set(value As String)
    txtPartner.Text = value
  End Set
End Property
```

Then, the page containing the user control can access the value like this:

```
myControl.CompanyName
```

Comment: So, in my .aspx page I have the usercontrol listed like this:
`<ucpartner:PartnerContacts ID="PartnerPrimaryContacts" Title="Partner Primary Contact" runat="server"></ucpartner:PartnerContacts>`
And in my .ascx I have:
`Public Property FName() As String Get Return txtPartnerFName.Text End Get Set(ByVal Value As String) txtPartnerFName.Text = Value End Set End Property`
So, db insert would look something like: 
`Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PC_FName", PartnerContacts.PartnerPrimaryContacts.FName.Text)`?

Comment: Just FName, since that's returning the Text property already.